# How to convert an image to a 3 channel image when type of input is not known?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image in opencv which I read from disk and I don't know its type during application development and I want to convert it to a 3 channel image.

Since I don't know its colour space when I am developing code I can not use cvCVTColor.

How can I convert colour space when I don't know the colour space at development time?

**Edit 1**

Assume that I want to an application that reads an image from a file and save it as 32 bit PNG file.

So I have this code:

```
 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
         string imageName=argv[1]; // assume that image name is always passed 
         auto image=imread(imageName);
          // convert it to 32 bit image
          imwrite("Outputimage.png",image);
  }
```

Comment: Where do you get the images from? Often it is easy to track the color space so let the caller tell the function about the image's color space.

Comment: @Micka I am reading it from a file. see my edited question.

Comment: The documentation for `imread` states that by default, it returns a 3-channel color image.

Comment: if you read it this way, it will always be a `CV_8UC3` in `BGR24` format, afaik.